# Polymorphic function object not working as a type in a template function, type name is not allowed

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement instanced rendering in opengl while using an ECS. As a solution I thought: instead of calling a draw function for each entity, call a draw function for each type of geometry. To do this I want to supply polymorphic draw functors which reside in geometry-specific namespaces, for instance TorusGeom namespace.

So I have a `std::map< std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<DrawFunctor> >`

and to add a specific draw functor, I have

```
template <typename T>
void addFunctor() const            // new entry iff map doesn't yet contain functor of type 
     {
         static_assert(std::is_base_of<DrawFunctor, T>::value, "invalid typename, not a DrawFunctor");
         using std::type_index;
         type_index functorType = type_index(typeid(T));
         if (functors.find(functorType) == functors.end()) 
             functors[functorType] = std::make_unique<T>(new T()); 
     }
```

however when I try to call addFunctor

```
entity->manager.addFunctor< TorusGeom::TorusDraw >();
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

That line gives the error `type name not allowed.` and I can't see why. In case its the way functors are defined:

```
struct DrawFunctor {
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
    virtual ~DrawFunctor() = default;
protected:
    DrawFunctor() {}
};
```

```
struct TorusDraw : public DrawFunctor {
    TorusDraw() : DrawFunctor() {} 
    void operator()() override final {
        glDrawElementsInstanced(...));
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your error message is saying, but surely you can't expect to pass a pointer argument (as returned by `new`) to a function taking a reference?

Comment: It seems like `addFunctor` should take `std::unique_ptr<DrawFunctor>`? But then you use the argument to construct a `T`. It seems you're confusing pointers with references, as well as one type with another.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell, as you've left some things out, and an attempt to recreate the symptom would take more effort than I'm able to spend.   As declared, `addFunctor<TorusGeom::TorusDraw>()` accepts a reference (`TorusGeom::TorusDraw &`), but you are passing it a pointer (`TorusGeom::TorusDraw *`)- which, often, I would expect to give a diagnostic of some form.

Comment: Please show full, unedited error messages. Your compiles tells you the line number and the column of the error, why do you think *we* don't need this information?

Comment: Why not just use a `std::function<void()>` here?  Why mess around with `unique_ptr`s and `DrawFunctor`s at all?

Comment: @MilesBudnek I was not aware of it, I will look into it as an alternative!

Comment: A bit off-topic for your current issue, but related to the problem. Using a Batch Rendering process would help. A BatchManager class will create buckets of batches where each batch will contain a specific rendering primitive such as `lines`, `triangle lists`, `triangle fans`, etc... Regardless of your "Geometry", you would send all of your `models` to the BatchManager's list of objects to be rendered based on a priority queue. When there are no buckets left to be filled and no more room in the buckets, the bucket with the highest priority queue will be sent to the GPU for rendering.

Comment: Does this help? [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a forward declaration of `class Manager` before `Entity`, thanks for the suggestions in the comments.